# Flutter - Type List<Dynamic> is not subtype of type Widget

Tags: list, flutter, widget

I have a program that uses a List, but I get this error, how to fix it?

```html
  @override
  Widget build(BuildContext context) {
    return Scaffold(
      body: Stack(children: [
        CustomScrollView(physics: BouncingScrollPhysics(), slivers: [
          _list(),
        ]),
      ]),
    );
  }

  _list() {
    return List.generate(
      actions.length,
      (i) => _card(actions[i]),
    );
  }


  _card(
String phrase,
  ) {
return SliverToBoxAdapter(
  child: Card(
    shape: RoundedRectangleBorder(
      side: BorderSide(color: Colors.black26, width: 0.1),
      borderRadius: BorderRadius.circular(10),
    ),
    margin: EdgeInsets.only(right: 50, left: 50, top: 20),
    child: InkWell(
      splashColor: Colors.black12,
      borderRadius: BorderRadius.circular(10),
      splashFactory: InkRipple.splashFactory,
      onTap: () => _speak(phrase),
      child: Column(children: <Widget>[
        SizedBox(height: 15.0),
        Padding(
          padding: EdgeInsets.only(left: 15, right: 15),
          child: Text(
            phrase,
            style: TextStyle(
                fontFamily: 'Circular',
                fontSize: 17.0,
                color: Colors.grey[800]),
          ),
        ),
        SizedBox(height: 15.0),
      ]),
    ),
  ),
);
  }
```

Answer (score 0):

Your method `_list()` returns a `List<Widget>`.

Therefore, you should remove the brackets in your `CustomScrollView`:

```
CustomScrollView(physics: BouncingScrollPhysics(), slivers: _list()),
```

Comment: By the way, check your other question for a better code structure: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/66191051/flutter-find-cards-by-names/66191770#66191770